# sending pdf attachment in email in Aol email

Tags: php, email, pdf

I am sending a pdf attachment within an email and am having an issue when trying to be opened in Aol mail. The attachment showing like on email abc.pdf (< 1 KB).The attachment says:

> Adobe Reader could not open'abc.pdf' because it is either not a
>   supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example,
>   it was sent as an email attachement and wasn't correctly decoded).

Here is my code:

```
include("walljs/mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();   
$mpdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('appstyle_pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($output);
$comname = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/","",$_POST['company']); 
$name = $dirname.str_replace(" ","-",$comname)."_".$time_stamp.".pdf";        
$mpdf->Output($name,"F");   

$file = $name;
$crlf = "\n";
$filename = basename($file);
$file_size = filesize($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file))); 
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header = "From: orders@enkapps.com \r\n"
      ."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
      ."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n"
      ."This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n" 
      ."--".$uid."\r\n"
      ."Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"
      ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
      .$message." 
      ".$companyinfo."\r\n\r\n"
      ."--".$uid."\r\n"
      ."Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"
      ."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
      ."Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n"
      .$content."\r\n\r\n"
      ."--".$uid."--";
```

Any Suggestions please.

Comment: Any debugging done? Such as looking at the mail source, smtp filtering headers, checking the attachment with `pdfinfo` etc? Nobody's going to help with that gruesome  manual mime construction copy pasta; consider PhpMailer/SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your headers in he string $headers like that :

```
    'Content-Type: application/pdf';
    'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"';
        'Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate';
    'Pragma: public';
```

Comment: after ."--".$uid."\r\n" line below code is added but i'm not succeed for Aol mail.

Comment: ."Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n"
."Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate\r\n"
."Pragma: public\r\n"